# #states not working properly in IE 9

Tags: 7, forms

I am using `#states` form API to do the show hide animation of one element based on the values of another form element.like follows,

```
$price['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
        ':input[id="edit-field-paid-event-und"]' => array('value' => 1),
    ),
);
```

It's working fine in all the browsers except in Internet explorer 9 and 10. Any solution for this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer from this [Link](https://api.drupal.org/comment/36623#comment-36623). So Internet Explorers never accepts element value as integer. I changed my code as follows it's working for me,

```
$price['#states'] = array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[id="edit-field-paid-event-und"]' => array('value' => '1'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I was using a function to set the value and was able to use this answer and (string) to fix IE11.

Comment: WTF! Damn IE. Thanks a lot for sharing the solution. Saved me lots of headaches.